# change line starting with# with sed -i

Tags: sed, repository, hashing

I want to uncomment a line in /etc/apt/sources.list to enable canonical repo but it seems it has a problem with # character I tried -e but I can't figure out if I'm doing it correctly

sed -i ' s/# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/g ' /etc/apt/sources.list

all I want is to change without using editors on a script

#deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu

to

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you've posted has unescaped forward slashes. You could escape them all with backslashes, or you could [use a different regex delimiter](https://backreference.org/2010/02/20/using-different-delimiters-in-sed/) so you don't have to escape all those slashes, e.g.

```
sed -i 's|# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu|deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu|' /etc/apt/sources.list
```